# Immersive fullscreen not hiding actionbar and statusbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-fullscreen, android-statusbar

I followed [the instructions on Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) to apply immersive fullscreen to my Activity with Navigation drawer.

The problem is the the Actionbar is not hiding. For the status bar, the texts just disappearad while the background color of the status still remains there.

**BEFORE**
[image: Before fullscreen]

**AFTER**
[image]
**Code**

```
// This snippet hides the system bars.
    private void hideSystemUI() {
        // Set the IMMERSIVE flag.
        // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the content
        // doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
        View mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);

        mIsActionBarVisible = false;
    }

    // This snippet shows the system bars. It does this by removing all the flags
// except for the ones that make the content appear under the system bars.
    private void showSystemUI() {
        View mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

        mIsActionBarVisible = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Please do younhave any idea what might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by explicitly hiding the ActionBar:

```
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
```